# Python string comparison not working as intended?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a [Codeforces problem](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/496/C) (I'm not in a middle of a contest so it's not cheating!) and I can't get the string comparison part correctly for some reason.

The gist of the problem is that, given an array of strings, I have to calculate how many columns I have to remove to make the strings lexicographically in order. So for the second test case scenario, we're given

```
case
care
test
code
```

And the answer should be 2, with the first and third columns being removed and resulting in

```
ae
ae
et
oe
```

Attached below is my code:

```
#some code to take the input and convert it to a list s
begin = 0
out_list = [[] for i in range(n)]
while begin < m: #m is the length of each string
    out_copy = out_list[:]
    for i in range(n): #n is the number of strings
        out_copy[i].append(s[i][begin])
    fine = True
    for i in range(1,n):
        if ''.join(out_copy[i]) < ''.join(out_copy[i-1]):
            fine = False
    if fine:
        out_list = out_copy
    begin += 1
#some code to output the result
```

`''.join(list)` is supposed to give me a string that is a concatenation of all the characters in the list, and the `<` operator should be enough of a comparator for the computer to return `False` for the first column since `c` is less than `t`... but something must not be quite right here. What's going on?

Comment: `p = o[:]` - that's a shallow copy. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @user2357112 - That's the only real way I knew how to copy the list... is there a better one? I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: @2012ssohn See this as to how to copy a list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: @user2357112, that's a deep copy. See http://ideone.com/Y8qomw.

Comment: @RSahu: No it's not. See http://ideone.com/e6J29O

Comment: With all due respect, gentlemen, could we discuss list copies on a different thread?

Comment: @user2357112, I see. That's a deep copy by one level only.

Comment: this is directly related to your question, actually :)

Comment: @Alik - My question is about string comparisons, not about list copies.

Comment: @2012ssohn you _think_ your problem is about string comparisons, but the problem is not about strings. Python compares strings correctly. _Your code_ copies list _incorrectly_ thus, `out_list` is being modified on each iteration regardless of `fine` flag

Comment: @2012ssohn use `pdb` or just insert `print out_list` somewhere inside `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
out_copy = out_list[:]
```

you make a [*shallow* copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy) of `out_list`. Thus, `out_list[i]` and `out_copy[i]` refer to the same object.

Notice, that you mutate `out_copy[i]` on each iteration, so `out_list[i]` is changed on each iteration regardless of `fine` value. You can confirm it by adding `print out_list` inside the loop

```
begin = 0
out_list = [[] for i in range(n)]
while begin < m: #m is the length of each string
    print out_list
    out_copy = out_list[:]
    .....
    .....
```

outputs

```
[[], [], [], []]
[['c'], ['c'], ['t'], ['c']]
[['c', 'a'], ['c', 'a'], ['t', 'e'], ['c', 'o']]
[['c', 'a', 's'], ['c', 'a', 'r'], ['t', 'e', 's'], ['c', 'o', 'd']]
```

---

Make a deep copy instead.

```
import copy
begin = 0
out_list = [[] for i in range(n)]
while begin < m: #m is the length of each string
    out_copy = copy.deepcopy(out_list)
    .....
    .....
print out_list
```

produces correct result

```
[['a', 'e'], ['a', 'e'], ['e', 't'], ['o', 'e']]
```